# Remove bottom border on active li element in CSS horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal nav that looks as follows:

[image: horizontal nav]

I'm trying to remove the bottom border for the actively selected li item, but for some reason the usual ways of doing this don't seem to be working. I've tried applying `margin-bottom: -1px;` and it didn't work.

Here's a JSFiddle with my CSS code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/s5ynF/8/

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.

update these CSS selectors to this:

```
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    height:25px;
}

#nav .home {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-bottom: -1px;   
}
```

I removed the `overflow:hidden;` that's why it wasn't working. I then applied a fixed height to the `.nav`

Comment: thanks, that works great! quick follow up question, the right and left border on the active li element now extend very slightly below the ul's bottom border (see http://jsfiddle.net/s5ynF/9/). what's the best way to fix that?

Comment: @rolling stone try changing the `margin-bottom` to -1px instead of -2px

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a different clear fix method as the `overflow: hidden` is what is stopping it from working.

I added an explicit height and removed `overflow: hidden` and it worked.